# Poisson conditional probability question

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, poisson-distribution

So I have a question that asks the following:

> The probability that $n$ electrons are emitted by a thermionic cathode in a time interval $t$ is given by a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda$. What is the probability that $n$ electrons are emitted in a time interval $t$  in which at least 2 electrons are emitted?

I've tried to use conditional probability with the Poisson pmf given that $n$ is more than or equal to 2 but I can't seem to get anywhere and at this point any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the number of electrons emitted in a time interval $t$. Note that $X\sim \text{Po}(\lambda)$. Then the probability is $$\mathbb P(X=n|X\ge 2)=\frac{\mathbb P(X=n\cap X\ge 2)}{\mathbb P(X\ge 2)}$$
It is easy to see that for $n=0,1;\mathbb P(X=n\cap X\ge 2)=0$. For $n\ge 2$, $$\frac{\mathbb P(X=n\cap X\ge 2)}{\mathbb P(X\ge 2)}=\frac{\mathbb P(X=n)}{1-\mathbb P(0\le X\le 1)}=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\cdot \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}}{1-\sum_{k=0}^1e^{-\lambda}\cdot \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}}$$

Comment: It doesn't sum up to one over n. I'm afraid it is not a pdf.

Comment: @Arash edited, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

First of all, $X\sim \mathcal{P}(\lambda t)$, i.e., $\Pr\{X=n\}=\frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda t}$. The probability that $n$ electrons are emitted, given at least 2 are emitted is:
$$\Pr\{X=n|X\geq 2\} = \frac{\Pr\{X=n, X\geq 2\}}{\Pr\{X\geq2 \}}$$
Note that
$$\Pr\{X=n, X\geq2\} = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda t}, & n\geq 2\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
and
$$\Pr\{X\geq2\}=\sum\limits_{k=2}^{+\infty}\frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda t}
=1-(1+\lambda t)e^{-\lambda t}$$
So,
$$\Pr\{X=n|X\geq2\}=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}\dfrac{e^{-\lambda t}}{1-(1+\lambda t)e^{-\lambda t}}, & n\geq 2\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: the rate over the time interval $t$ is $\lambda$, not $\lambda t$. I think that's what it says in the question?

Comment: In this problem, the rate is the constant $\lambda$. It means that on average, the ratio of the number of occurrences to the time interval, for any interval, is constant. If something happens once a second, it happens 60 times in a minute, and so on. The rate, however, can be time-variant, say $\lambda(t)$. In that case, instead of $\lambda t$, the parameter of the exponential distribution will be $\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\lambda(t)dt$.

Comment: The probability that $n$ electrons are emitted by a thermionic cathode in a time interval $t$ is given by a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda$. So pretty sure it means that the rate is $\lambda$ per $t$ units of time, meaning that the rate would only be $\lambda t$ if $t^2$ units of time were involved

Comment: Please for example look at page 378 of the 4th edition of Papoulis' *Probability, Random Variables, and Stochastic Processes*, Example 9-5: Poisson Process

Comment: I do have knowledge in Poisson processes. This however is clearly not what it means in the question

Comment: No doubt you have the knowledge, but we all make mistakes. It was just a reminder. I too will triple check my answer.

Comment: Maybe you are right, and the question intends what you are inferring. But I suppose it is not customary. Cheers :)